# Apache Config Different Site on Subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, configuration

I have seen a few questions on this general topic, but they haven't addressed my case.

I have a server running apache.  I want to direct all traffic to one document root, except for traffic to a "directory" (example.com/something), which I want to direct to a different document root.  What directives/virtualhosts do I need to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be a bit more specific about the end goal you're trying to achieve?

Here are some things that *might* do what you need.

- Using `Alias /something/ "/var/www/second_document_root"`
- Using two VirtualHosts and `Redirect http://somesite.com/something http://someothersite.com`
- Using mod_proxy and something like `ProxyPass /something/ http://someothersite.com`

Comment: I found that Alias worked shortly after asking, I was waiting until the mandatory 8-hour period was over so I could answer my own question.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

As [Christopher Karel](https://serverfault.com/users/29354/christopher-karel%20Christopher%20Karel) has mentioned, Alias was the correct solution to the issue.  I was able to set up a single VHost for the main website (example.com), and set and alias for example.com/something using this line:

```
Alias /something /var/www/something_dir/
```